# SWIG passing multiple arrays from python to C

Tags: c, numpy, swig

Using SWIG, I've been trying to wrap a C function with the following signature:

`void mainline(double *data, int datasize, char *metadata, int metasize, char *path)`

The python caller is passing numpy 1D arrays, so (ignoring the final char *path for the moment), I thought an interface file such as:

```
%module testit

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
void mainline(double* dataPtr, int datasize, char* headerPtr, int headersize);
%}
%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
import_array();
%}
%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1 int DIM1) {(double* dataPtr, int datasize)}
%apply (char* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(char* headerPtr, int headersize)}

%inline %{
    void testit_mainline(double* dataPtr, int datasize, char* headerPtr, int headersize) {
        return mainline(dataPtr, datasize, headerPtr, headersize);
    }
%}
```

would do it. However, when I call from python with

```
import testit
import numpy as np
dataPtr = np.zeros(5)
datasize = dataPtr.size
headerPtr = "Just testing"
headersize = len(headerPtr)
testit.testit_mainline(dataPtr,datasize,headerPtr,headersize)
```

I get the error "testit_mainline() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" ?

Sure enough, if I look at the generated c wrapper "testit_wrap.c" I see lines like:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_testit_mainline(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
...
...
PyObject *swig_obj[3] ;
```

despite the obvious 4 arguments in my interface file. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a multi-parameter typemap, then multiple C parameters are represented by one Python parameter.  In this case, A single numpy array or Python list can be used as a parameter for the pointer and size, since Python knows the length of its objects and the typemap accounts for that.

Also, the error wanted 3 parameters because the second array wasn't matching the types properly.  the [numpy.i documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/swig.interface-file.html) indicated `signed char` was supported, not `char` (SWIG can be pedantic), so I used that and it matched the typemap properly and only required two parameters.

Here's a minimal example:

test.i:

```
%module test

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
%}

%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* dataPtr, int datasize)}
%apply (signed char* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(char* headerPtr, int headersize)}

%inline %{
    void mainline(double* dataPtr, int datasize, char* headerPtr, int headersize) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < datasize; ++i)
            printf("[%zu] %lf\n",i,dataPtr[i]);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < headersize; ++i)
            printf("[%zu] %hhd\n",i,headerPtr[i]);
    }
%}
```

Output:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.mainline([1.0,1.5,2.0],[1,2,3])
[0] 1.000000
[1] 1.500000
[2] 2.000000
[0] 1
[1] 2
[2] 3
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1.1,2.2,3.3])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3],dtype=np.int8)
>>> test.mainline(a,b)
[0] 1.100000
[1] 2.200000
[2] 3.300000
[0] 1
[1] 2
[2] 3
```

Comment: This compiles and runs (thanks!). But why is headerPtr being treated as an int? Eg, in your example, if we change to  b = ["a","b"], I get a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" ?

Comment: @gwhg Because the signed char* IN_ARRAY type map I used was written that way...to expect signed 8-bit ints.

Comment: That's a little confusing .... the only place I can see you've defined it as an integer is in the calling python routine? So I replaced the definition of b to b = np.array(list("ABCD"),dtype='S') and still get an error - although it's now a cast error. I guess the point is, I want to pass a numpy array of doubles and a couple of strings to the C function, not doubles and ints.

Comment: @gwhg It's in the [numpy.i documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/swig.interface-file.html).  It supports various signed/unsigned integer sizes from int8 (char) through int64 (long long), plus float and double.  It doesn't look like numpy.i provides typemaps for characters.  You know that a C array of `char x[10]` can be assigned like `x[0] = 1` as well as `x[0] = 'a'`, right?  It's all in how the typemaps were actually implemented.

Comment: Also just passing b=["ABCD"] fails with the same "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10", so somewhere else SWIG is expecting am integer, not a char *

Comment: @gwhg The numpy typemap *expects* a numpy array of int8.  If you don't want that behavior, don't use a numpy.i typemap.

Comment: @gwhg If you want to pass a string, change my example and add `char* path` as the last parameter to mainline and print it in the body, then call `mainline([1,2,3],[4,5,6],'hello')` and it will work. The default SWIG typemap will accept a Unicode string as input and convert to a null-terminated UTF-8-encoded `char*` in the C function.

Comment: Thanks - that's the bit I was missing, mixing numpy.i and std SWIG typemaps!